# Angularjs Filter : model in child and flilter in parent in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
        <p>Filtering input:</p>
        <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test | orderBy:'country'">
        {{ (x.name | uppercase) + ', ' + x.country }}
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
            {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
            {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
            {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
        ];
    });
    app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
    });
</script>
```

In short this filter is not work.

Rule 1 : Model(test) must be in second controller.

Rule 2 : Data and ng-repeat must be in mainCtrl.

Thanks.

Comment: This is right. Thanks   @Amit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is basically, filtering value in parent controller based on child controller's variable.

One way to do this is to expose the `test` in parent controller.

I made small change to your `ng-model` attribute.

```
<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <p>Filtering input:</p>
    <p><input type="text" ng-model="$parent.test"></p>
</div>
```

I have exposed the same to parent controller, hence the change made in secondCntrl will be exposed to `test` in parent and your filter works fine.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmitGoda/s7osz6gw/) of it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3974so0/

The problem is that the `test` variable in the `filter` statement is not the same variable declared in the ngModel if the input.

Usually variables are declared in parent scopes and used in children scopes, the opposite of what you want use.

In order to let the father scope to use a variable of the children scope is to register a service that share that variable.

**update:**

Here is the implementation with a service, following constraints you specified 1. and 2.

https://jsfiddle.net/j3974so0/1/

Comment: This answer is also right.But unfortunately only 1 answer can be mark So Sorry Morels.
And Thanks